# How to combine multiple while True function processes?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, while-loop, python-multiprocessing

I'm very new to programming and python, can you please help me with the code I wrote? I don't know how to get it to work. Must I use class for it? Also how can the same variable be used in multiple functions? Do I need the multiprocessing?

Here's my test code:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process

def p1():
    while True:
        a = 1+1
        sleep(1)

def p2():
    while True:
        b = 1+1
        sleep(1)

def p3():
    while True:
        c = a+b
        print c
        sleep(1)

try:
    a1 = Process(target = p1)
    a2 = Process(target = p2)
    a3 = Process(target = p3)

    a1.start()
    a2.start()
    a3.start()
```

It says that I have an invalid syntax at the last line which is empty. But I'm pretty certain even without the syntax my code wouldn't work, can you please help? What can be changed?

Comment: You have a syntax error because there has to come some `except` after the `try`.

Comment: Look at the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: "Do I need the multiprocessing?" Depends. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: (1) The `p1` and `p2` functions will run endlessly. That's probably not what you want. (2) Variables defined within one function (for example `a` in `p1`) are local to that function; thus, `p3` won't know anything about `a` and `b` and will fail because those variables are undefined. (3) Your `try-except` is incomplete, as noted by others.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. @tobias_k I want to make in each function an algorithm or some calculation and all those function outputs then will be combined. It seems it's better to be done with class no?

Comment: @FMc well I want to run it endlessly, the 1+1 is just an example of something much bigger. Also the try-except is fixed, thank you all.

Comment: Does is have to run in multiple processes/threads? Maybe you could use a bunch of generator functions instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to tell without knowing what exactly you want to achieve with that code, but maybe you do not need processes or thread alltogether. Have you tried generator functions instead?

```
def p1(a=0):
    while True:
        yield a
        a = a + 1

def p2(b=0):
    while True:
        yield b
        b = b + 1

def p3(a, b):
    c = a + b
    print c

a_gen = p1()
b_gen = p2(3)
for _ in range(5):
    a = next(a_gen)
    b = next(b_gen)
    p3(a, b)
```

This will have `p1` and `p2` generate consecutive values from their respective algorithm and return them to be combined by `p3`. (Assuming that `p2` does something different than `p1`; otherwise you can just use the same generator function for both.) All in all, this might be much cleaner than using different threads and some global state manipulated by those threads.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!!! I changed your code a bit and added my algorithms in functions and it is putting them together as I needed. Thank you again @tobias_k .